# Editing Recoil Warzone

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I have this code and Im trying to understand it. Which part of the code would I need to edit to change the recoil pattern.

```
if recoil then
    repeat
        Sleep(49)
        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            break
        end
        MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)
        Sleep(49)
        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            break
        end
        MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)
        Sleep(25)
        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            break
        end
```

This is just part of the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edit the numbers `2` in `MoveMouseRelative`.  The bigger the number the stronger the anti-recoil.

Comment: okay will do. Do you know what the sleep function does?

also what does the first number do(0)?

Comment: first number = horizontal component of move (right) in pixels, second = vertical (down), sleep = time delay between movements in milliseconds

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!